# MySQL - динамическое удаление данных.

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Реализую личные сообщения на сайте. Решил спросить, что будет оптимальным способом удаления? Будет хорошо, если пользователь будет динамически удалять свои сообщения (через DELETE) или же помечать в дополнительное поле например (close) = 1, тем самым говоря, что сообщение удалено.

Так же, часто на многих динамических сайта начал замечать такую функцию: При удаление сообщения, поста и т.д. оно исчезает и появляется кнопка восстановить. Скорее всего это сообщение не удалятся, а помечается дополнительным полем? Я прав? Что будет лучше всего?

p.s. И еще сразу один вопрос. Для личных сообщений использовать лишь одну таблицу или нужно для каждого пользователя? За ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще желательно бы сохранять сообщения. Если не в основной базе, то в каких-то логах. Вдруг там мат, оскорбление.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.
А что на счет этого:

"p.s. И еще сразу один вопрос. Для личных сообщений использовать лишь одну таблицу или нужно для каждого пользователя? За ранее спасибо!"

Comment: выучить русский язык "Заранее" слитно пишется.

Одну таблицу, для всех сообщений!

Comment: @Shrek, всегда троллишь?

Comment: ты определение этого слова-то знаешь?

Знаешь читать вопросы, которые мало того написаны некорректно, да еще и беда с русским языком, такая лажа получается. Я не конкретно про данный вопрос, а вообще. Если ты не уважаешь язык, и привык к тому что, даже на собеседованиях пишут, "Превед" и "ИМХО" , то ... а про правила написания слов,их обороты , приставки и прочее я вообще молчу, деградация полная.

Comment: Обычно, по моему опыту, все сообщения хранятся в одной таблице.

Comment: @miss_julie, Благодарю.

@Shrek, ОК. С русским языком у меня все в порядке - опечатка. А у тебя в комментарии уже куча ошибок. 1. С большой буквы начало предложения. 2. После "Знаешь" ставится запятая, так как это вводное слово. 3. Перед запятыми не ставятся пробелы - они ставятся после их... Не нужно людей правильно учить писать. Решил помочь - помоги. ОК?